# How to get value from JsValue?

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework

For Example:
My Db stores following Json. Form Following json I need to extract the value of particular field.

```
"student": [
                                          {
                                    "name": "Xyz",
                                    "college": "abc",
                                    "student_id":{
                                       "$oid": "59a9314f6d0000920962e247"
                                     }},
                                           {
                                    "name": "DDD",
                                    "college": "opop",
                                    "student_id":{
                                        "$oid": "59a9314f6d0000920962e257"
                                }}
                                ]
```

How can I pick only the value of "$oid" and save json in following way:

```
"student": [
                                          {
                                    "name": "Xyz",
                                    "college": "abc",
                                    "student_id":
                                      "59a9314f6d0000920962e247"
                                     },
                                           {
                                    "name": "DDD",
                                    "college": "opop",
                                    "student_id":
                                      "59a9314f6d0000920962e257"
                                }
                                ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I'm reading it from client side as -

```
String Json = null;
JsonNode body = request().body().asJson();
Json = body.toString();
Logger.info(Json);
String role = body.get("role").get("role").asText();
users.firstName = body.get("firstName").asText();
users.lastName = body.get("lastName").asText();
```

You need to change the definition of `JsonNode body = request().body().asJson();` and the other code as per your scenario to get it from db.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace `"student_id"` jsValue with string value as below:

```
    val original: JsValue = Json.parse(
      """ {"student": [
      {
        "name": "Xyz",
        "college": "abc",
        "student_id":{
        "$oid": "59a9314f6d0000920962e247"
      }},
      {
        "name": "DDD",
        "college": "opop",
        "student_id":{
        "$oid": "59a9314f6d0000920962e257"
      }}
      ]}""")

    val changed = original.as[JsObject] ++ Json.obj(
      "student" -> Json.arr {
        original.transform((__ \ 'student)
          .json.pick[JsArray])
          .getOrElse(Json.arr())
          .value.map(e => {
          val value = e.transform((__ \ 'student_id \ '$oid).json.pick[JsString]).get
          e.as[JsObject] ++ Json.obj("student_id" -> value)
        })
      })
    println(Json.stringify(changed))

//Result:
{"student":[[{"name":"Xyz","college":"abc","student_id":"59a9314f6d0000920962e247"},{"name":"DDD","college":"opop","student_id":"59a9314f6d0000920962e257"}]]}
```